# Ideal generated by x and y in the ring of polynomials with real coefficients

Tags: group-theory, ideals

Consider $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ and $I,J$ ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ given by $I=J =(x,y)$. In lecture, my professor told us that $x^2+y^2 \neq ij$ for some $i,j \in (x,y)$. Although this is somewhat obvious by inspection, how do we prove it?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$?

Comment: Yes, I just updated it.

Comment: The easy way is saying that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is a UFD, and so a factorization over $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ would give you one over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, but the unique factorization there is $x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$, which requires coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: **Hint:** The statement is false in $\Bbb C[x,y]$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. By inspection of exponents in $i,j$ prove that both must be of the form $ax+by$ for some $a,b\in\Bbb R$.
2. Conclude by matching coefficients in $(ax+by)(cx+dy)$.